# Modx pdoMenu как вывести только первый уровень?

Tags: modx, revo, pdoresource, pdotools

Структура меню такая:

```
-Документ без вложенности
-Документ без вложенности
-Документ с 1-уровневой вложенностью
--вложженость
-Документ с 1-уровневой вложенностью
--вложженость
-Документ с 1-уровневой вложенностью
--вложженость
--вложженость
```

Естественно кол-во документов с вложенностью и без неизвестно.

Мне нужно вывести все пункты меню первого уровня, даже тех, у которых нет вложености

**pdoMenu** использую, но наверное он такое не может делать,
`&where = {isFolder=1}` - **не подходит, так как тогда вывод будет осуществляться только родителей, у которых есть вложенность, а вот у которых нет ее фиг тебе, а не вывод.**

Умеет ли такое **pdoResources** или как быть в такой ситуации?

```
[[!pdoMenu?
&parents=`-1`
&level=`1`
&limit=`6`
&tplOuter=`BottomMenuTplOuter`
&tpl = `BottomMenuTpl`
]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[!pdoMenu?
&parents=`0`
&resources=`-1`
&level=`1`
&limit=`6`
&tplOuter=`BottomMenuTplOuter`
&tpl = `BottomMenuTpl`
]]
```

Если надо исключить ресурс/ресурсы используйте &resources. Это все есть в документации https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdomenu
&resources      Список ресурсов для вывода в результатах, через запятую. Если id ресурса начинается с дефиса, этот ресурс исключается из выборки.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать так:

```
[[!pdoMenu?
&parents=`-1`
&displayStart=`1`
&level=`1`
&tplOuter=`BottomMenuTplOuter`
&tpl = `BottomMenuTpl`
]]
```

Если это не совсем верно, прошу объяснить

Comment: Попробуйте &parents=`0` тогда и без &displayStart=`1` должен показывать все меню 1-го уровня

Comment: @Tunker если &parent=0, то выводится главная страница, а ее нужно исключить

Comment: Вы не уточняли, чтобы без главной страницы, тогда все так, знак минус означает ресурс, который выводить не надо, т.е. у вас все ресурсы кроме первого

Comment: @Tunker напишите ответом, отмечу решением